# SQL Server 2000 Exclusive Locking

Tags: locking, sql-server-2000

My setup - One server with two SQL Server 2000 instances, INSTANCE1 and INSTANCE2. Each instance has 1 DB, DBprod and DBstag.

I have a situation where I need to prepare invoices for several customers so I would like to place an exclusive lock on a table while I fetch an invoice number from INSTANCE1.DBprod.LastInvoiceNumber to INSTANCE2.DBstag, perform soem calculation, prepare an invoice and then insert the invoice (header and detail) to INSTANCE1.DBprod, then update INSTANCE1.DBprod.LastInvoiceNumber, repeat for the next customer and then release the lock after I am finished with all the customers.

> begin trans inv
>
> EXCLUSIVELY LOCK
>   INSTANCE1.DBprod.LastInvoiceNumber
>
> open customer cursor
>
> fetch next from customer
>
> get invoice number from
>   INSTANCE1.DBprod.LastInvoiceNumber
>
> prepare invoice
>
> insert invoice to INSTANCE1.DBprod
>
> update
>   INSTANCE1.DBprod.LastInvoiceNumber
>   (increment by 1)
>
> fetch next from customer (prepare next
>   customer invoice)
>
> close customer cursor
>
> commit trans inv
>
> RELEASE LOCK ON
>   INSTANCE1.DBprod.LastInvoiceNumber

Would this be my solution

> SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL
>   SERIALIZABLE

There is an accounting application using INSTANCE1.DBprod.LastInvoiceNumber which is why I want to exclusively lock the table until I am finished posting all my invoices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the easiest ways is use [sp_getapplock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933410%28SQL.80%29.aspx) to allow only one session. Other sessions will wait/fail

This is independent of lock granularity and isolation and it often better in this scenario. Using SERIALIZABLE isn't exclusive : you'd need TABLOCKX. But then other readers on the table are blocked too

sp_getapplock will apply only to the scope of this code.

Comment: I am preparing the invoices via a stored proc. My intention is to block all applications from using the INSTANCE1.DBprod.LastInvoiceNumber until I am finished posting all my invoices...I'll look into your suggestion.